# How do I give Pycharm camera access on a mac to use with OpenCV? Python code works in terminal but does not work in Pycharm

Tags: python, opencv

This code works fine when I run it in terminal with a virtual environment. I believe this is being caused by Pycharm not having camera access. This is my best guess because when I ran in terminal, terminal asked for camera access but camera access is never asked for when I run in Pycharm.

I tried `tccutil reset Camera com.jetbrains.pycharm` but that did not fix my issue.

Error:

```
False None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/troy/PycharmProjects/OpenCV/Test.py", line 14, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("Video", img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.3.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

cap.set(3, 640)
cap.set(4, 480)

if not (cap.isOpened()):
    print("Camera Error")

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    print(success, img)
    cv2.imshow("Video", img)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default camera, you can change it to

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```